# Problems with shipping methods - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

For the Shipping Method, I have configured the table rates with a CSV (to set a different price for the countries we send). This is the CSV that I am using ():

```
Country, Region/State, Zip/Postal Code,# of Items (and above), Shipping Price
NLD,*,*,0,4.55
BEL,*,*,0,5.74
DEU,*,*,0,6.57
FRA,*,*,0,9.88
ESP,*,*,0,11.53
```

My problem is that if the client has an added address, the system does not show the price of the shipping cost and I receive the following message:

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

In the following image you can see it better:

[image]

If this client adds a new address, the price of the shipping method appears correctly, in the following image you can see it better:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

**UPDATE 1**

When I display the option of Estimate Shipping and tax, the price for this country appears correctly, but below in the summary, the price is 0.00€. 
This is what you see in the shopping cart summary:

[image]

On the next screen (EXPRESS CHECKOUT) I receive the error message that I put above in the SHIPPING METHODS section: "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time). To obtain the correct shipping costs, I need to add a new shipping address every time. Is there a way to automatically take the default shipping address and the correct shipping price?

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

I have detected that when I click on the address that the customer has saved, the shipping form is updated and the same message that appears in the image reappears, but I also receive this error by the console. Any idea of ​​the problem?

Comment: Please confirm that your saved shipping address contains shipping country that you defined in table rates.

Comment: Hi, the address I had saved is Netherland. The new address that I add in the second image is the same address that I had saved (also in Netherland)

Comment: Have you disable this Onepage checkout and use default Magento checkout and check what happen.

Comment: If I disable this option, I can not do the payment

Comment: and in the shopping cart I can see the same, shipping costs 0.00. But sometimes the right price appears. It's very strange!

Comment: I have updated the question with more information